# Is it possible to create a QR code scanner with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I'm looking for a method to scan QR codes using jQuery Mobile but I haven't found any guide or anything.

I wanted to ask you if there are methods and if you can help me make it happen.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using zxing/ngx-scanner with angular found [here](https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner), it works great, seeing it is a javascript library it may be able to work with jQuery.

Comment: Good! Thank you :)